# Showing <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused> not able to use localhost for multiple applications!

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bashrc, curl, localhost

I have been unable to install a number of applications including anaconda and druid on my ubuntu 16.04 system because whenever they try to open a url using localhost it flashes a message:
 `urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused`

I am unable to even use curl as whenever I try something like,

```
curl -X OST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @quickstart/tutorial/wikipedia-index.json http://localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task
```

It flashes the message:
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8090: Connection refused`

As this problem has propagated across multiple applications I think there is some problem with my localhost and ports connection. I really need help, I'm not able to do anything on ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

It means 8090 port is not available yet, maybe any service running on it. you can resolve this error by changing port in overlord/runtime.properties.
You can add this.